# Configure apt to delay update of specific packages

Tags: debian, apt

On Debian, in my apt sources I have put the source for opera-stable browser.

opera is updated very often on their repo, almost daily or every other day.
That's very frequent and every time a large download.

Is there a way to skip its (somehow automatic) update for a specific duration or something similar by configuring apt in a specific way? Updating that package only once per month would be sufficient for me.

Opera is an example here, but there is other closed source software that I have in my apt repo that I would like to be managed in the same manner.

Comment: Are you looking for [Excluding Packages from Apt-Get Upgrade](https://tecadmin.net/exclude-packages-from-apt-upgrade/)?

Comment: Ok, `hold` is an acceptable option. I used to use `+` key stroke in `aptitude` to select upgradable packages and was disappointed that it installed also the packages in `hold` state. Your comment made me dig and I discovered the `U` key stroke instead of `+`. So `Hold` (`=` key stroke) + `U` is the answer for `aptitude`. Thanks. Do you know a way to remove the `hold` mark on a package after a specific duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the Opera Debian package from updates, use the
following command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold package_name
```

This will turn off the updates of the specified package(s) from
automatic upgrades and also from manual upgrades.

To undo the hold, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

For more information for Debian and other Linux distributions, see
[Excluding Packages from Apt-Get Upgrade](https://tecadmin.net/exclude-packages-from-apt-upgrade/).

Answer (score 0):

- Hit the Super key (Win-logo),
- type "update"
- and click in the pinkish icon that appears (Software & Updates).
- Click on the /Updates\ -tab in the top row.
- Find "Automatically check for updates:" below;
  set it to anything you like.

*You will most likely find it to be set to Daily, currently*

Comment: Thank you, I guess your answer is with Gnome DE. I run KDE, but there is a similar configuration option with almost the same wordings. This doesn't exactly answer my problem but interested me as well.